# Вывести Max() с запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Привет

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `energy`=0";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
       print_r($obj);
       print_r($obj->MAX('id'));
       echo '<br>';
       $obj->MAX('id');
    }

stdClass Object ( [MAX(`id`)] => 110 )
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::MAX() in Z:\home\localhost\www\bd.php on line 18

Как быть?Можно было юзать mysql_fetch_array() и выбрать 1 элемент массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может как-то обозвать поле, а потом уже к нему обращаться. Например как-то так?

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(`id`) AS max_id FROM `users` WHERE `energy`=0";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
       print_r($obj);
       print_r($obj->max_id);
       echo '<br>';
       //$obj->MAX('id'); - это вообще что?
    }

//stdClass Object ( [MAX(`id`)] => 110 ) - и это?
```

Comment: stdClass Object ( [MAX(`id`)] => 110 ) это был показан результат print_r .А $obj->MAX('id') это пытался получить значение объекта.У меня все выйшло.Спасибо.